# Does a technical stop trigger EU flight compensation rules?

Tags: eu, passenger-rights

If I am flying, say, Addis Ababa (ABB) to Toronto (YYZ) on Ethiopian, do EU passenger rights rules apply?

The flight (Ethiopian Airlines 552) makes a 45 minute technical stop in Dublin.

[This site](https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/passenger-rights/air/index_en.htm) is not clear on the matter, but I'm guessing the rules probably do not apply. Is that correct?

It would be in this category:

> If your flight departs from the EU to a non-EU country operated by an EU or a non-EU airline

In other words, if this flight is delayed or cancelled, the question is whether  EU passenger rights apply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*edit:*
[Sabine](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/40603/sabine) made me aware in the comments that I misunderstood the purpose of your question. I thought you were asking whether the technical stop of 45 minutes make you eligible for compensation, but it seems you're asking if a stop in a EU country makes you eligible for compensation in case of a delay.

I would think the answer to this is **no**, a stop in a EU country does not make you eligible for compensation under the EU air passenger rights. Your flight neither starts nor stops in a EU country, nor is the flight operated by a EU airline. But I can't provide the sources for this claim.

*old answer:*
Your flight is neither delayed nor cancelled, so you're not eligible for any compensation. The 45 minutes technical stop is a scheduled stop that is even listed on the Ethiopian website. It's just a regular part of the flight.

Comment: I think OP is asking a hypothetical question, if he were flying this flight and it got delayed, would he be entitled for compensation - not about a compensation for the 45min technical break (which would be too short to grant compensation either way)

Comment: That is a good point, I absolutely agree with your assesment. I think OP could make this much clearer by removing the details about the duration and the purpose of the stop. I can't answer that question, so I will delete my answer. (edit: It seems I can't delete my answer, only edit and flag - and the flag link does absolutely nothing.)

Comment: I think your correct, as the [Regulation 261/2004](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/HTML/?uri=CELEX:32004R0261) (which the explainer website the OP linked to above is based on) under "Article 3: Scope", says it applies "(a) to passengers departing from an airport located in the territory of a Member State to which the Treaty applies; (b) to passengers departing from an airport located in a third country to an airport situated in the territory of a Member State to which the Treaty applies"

Comment: @anotherdave Assuming that "departing from an airport" does not apply to those leaving after sitting on the tarmac for 45 min, I think this answers the question. Maybe it should be part of the answer, but I'll accept it, thanks.